# Preventing DPDK packet loss in L2 forwarding

Tags: networking, dpdk

Hello I have implemented pingpong for DPDK. 
with the client sending the packets and the server receiving the packets and then returning them.

The server part is implemented similar to the L2 forwarding sample in the DPDK official website.

While doing the L2 forwarding I have noticed that there are packet losses while I forward the the packets from the receiver queue to the transfer queue.

My question is ... is there a way to make the packet loss into zero?

I could not find the solution to this since the sample applications from DPDK website all have packet losses.

the packet losses are counted by the callback function below

```
rte_eth_tx_buffer_set_err_callback(tx_buffer[portid], rte_eth_tx_buffer_count_callback, &port_statistics[portid].dropped);
```

this is the result I have from the L2 forwarding

```
Port statistics ====================================
Statistics for port 0 ------------------------------
Packets sent:                   384126              
Packets received:               379889              
Packets dropped:                  4237              
Aggregate statistics ===============================
Total packets sent:             384126              
Total packets received:         379889              
Total packets dropped:            4237              
====================================================
```

since my implementation is just pingpong and have very simple implementation, I don't believe that there should be any packet losses in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Packets dropped` counter is getting increased in `rte_eth_tx_buffer_flush()` when function `rte_eth_tx_burst()` cannot transmit packets to the destination port.

The `rte_eth_tx_burst()` function simply calls your `tx_pkt_burst()` PMD callback, so it is hard to say why it is failing without information about your underneath PMD. So the following section is quite a bit of speculation...

So in general, `rte_eth_tx_burst()` fails because TX queue is full. TX queue is getting full because underneath device unable to send the packets with the rate you provide.

There are few cases when it might happen:

1. Your RX port speed is bigger than your TX port speed (most probably it is not your case).
2. Your RX and TX ports have the same speed, but you add some extra packets in your app, so they are not fit anymore (might be your case).
3. Your NIC is pausing transmission due to the flow control, so you have those drops (most probably that is your case).

So, if my guess is correct, just disable Ethernet flow control on your client side with the `ethtool`:

```
ethtool -A eth0 tx off rx off
```

If my guess is incorrect, then on your server side dig into the PMD counters with `rte_eth_stats_get()` and `rte_eth_xstats_get()` to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  But my case was far more elementary than what you have suspected. The reason for me was some of the packets did not have the destination in the header, after fixing this there was no drop of packets.  However, I experienced your guessed case when I did the stress test with the L2 forwarding.